# Google Cloud Message Sandbox

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I followed the [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html) to implement push notifications on my Android App (Google Cloud Message). I managed to successfully implement these messages but now I'm concerned about dev/production environment. There is only one API key (in opposite of Apple who has sandbox key and production key). How you guys deal with this? I don't want my gcm tests firing real messages to users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `dry_run` field :

> dry_run
>
> If included, allows developers to test their request without actually
>   sending a message. Optional. The default value is false, and must be a
>   JSON boolean.

If it doesn't work you can try the `restricted_package_name` field with an invalid package name. I haven't tried it, but it might behave the way you want.

> restricted_package_name
>
> A string containing the package name of your application. When set,
>   messages will only be sent to registration IDs that match the package
>   name. Optional.

The quotes were taken from the [GCM Architectural Overview](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a new API Project.

- From the Google Developer Console create a new sandbox API project
- Create a new public API access key for server applications
- Server sandbox environments push using the public API access key for server applications from the sandbox API project
- Android debug builds use
  the project ID from the sandbox API project