# Can Android App notifications be tested without pushing app to live?

Tags: android

I work in software validation and my friend is working on an app for her business with a developer in India.  The developer working on it is saying that it has to be uploaded and live in order to test notifications.  I don't work with apps so I'm not sure - anyone have input on this?  Seems odd to me...

Thank you!
Morgan

Comment: this should help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15912405/google-cloud-message-sandbox

Comment: notifications such as GCM?

Comment: Or do you mean `Notification` -- icons in the status bar and so forth?

Comment: Read this:http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html
Then you can send POST request to https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send with headers Authorization key=<your_key>    Content-Type application/json and body {
  "collapse_key": "demo",
  "registration_ids": [
    "your_device_reg_id"
  ],
  "data": {
    "your_value_key": "your_value_body"
  }
}

Comment: If you're asking about Push Notifications, then no it doesn't have to be uploaded.

Comment: I'll get further information and let you know - thanks for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GCM (Google cloude messaging / Push Notifications), there will not be any problem in testing it without making it live.